# How to populate data onto a dropdown rendered inside a table column api in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api

im trying to populate all the dropdowns in my table using a single api request.

Im trying to develop a forms portal. one of the pages have a table with dropdowns on a few columns. this table has add row and delete row features. now i'm trying to populate the dropdowns in the table(4 specifically) using an api call. the api call is succesfull in obtaining the data to be populated onto the state variables. but since im using a single class for the calling and rendering function i'm having trouble rendering the data to the corresponding columns. how do i render the data in this.state.backupof into the select tags of the first column. please help me...

```
export default class EditableTable extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
    .get(`http://xx.xx.x.xxx:8000/backup_request/dropdown`)
    .then(response=>response.data)
    .then(data=>{this.setState({backupof: data.backup_of_list});
                 this.setState({servertypelist:data.server_type_list});
                 this.setState({frequencylist:data.frequency_list});
                 this.setState({backupdrivelist:data.backup_drive})
                 console.log(this.state.backupof,"axios worked");});
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:[],
      backupof:[],
    servertypelist:[],
    frequencylist:[],
    backupdrivelist:[],
    };
    this.columns = [
      {
        title: 'Backup Of',
        dataIndex: 'backupOf',
        align:'center',
        render: (select, record) =>

          this.state.dataSource.length >= 1 ? (
                    <Select defaultValue='Select' name='backupOf' >
                      {this.state.backupof.map(person => (
                      <Option value={person.name} label={person.name} key={person.name}>
                      {person.name}
                      </Option>
                       ))}
                    </Select>) : null

      },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it...
I called the api in the parent form and then passed the value to the child table.

```
                        <Select defaultValue='Select' name='requestType'>
                            {this.props.requesttypedrop.map(person => (
                                <Option value={person.name} label={person.name} key={person.name}>
                                  {person.name}
                                </Option>
                             ))} 
                        </Select>
```

this is the api call in parent

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
    .get(`http://xx.xx.x.xxx:8000/asset_request/request_type_dropdown/`)
    .then(response=>response.data)
    .then(data=>{this.setState({request_type:data.request_type_list});
                this.setState({required_type:data.server_type_list});
                this.setState({asset_type:data.frequency_list});
                this.setState({loading:false});
              })
    .catch(error => {console.log(error);});
  }
```

it was an isssue of timing. doing this solved it.